# Почему не работает .on('click') на динамическом элементе?

Tags: jquery

Нужно сделать автопоиск по элементам из JSON-файла.

Делаю ajax request, в форму добавляю список `.page-header__earch-autocomplete`, сами варианты - `li.page-header__search-request`.

При введении в `input` символов, подходящие варианты появляются, но к ним не привязывается событие `.on('click')`, чтобы выбранный вариант подставился в `input`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var searchTopIcon = $('.page-header__search--top .page-header__search-icon ');
  var searchTopInput = $('#search-top');
  var searchTopAutocomplete = $('.page-header__search--top .page-header__search-autocomplete');

  searchTopIcon.click(function(){  // input  скрыт через display none в СSS, появляется по щелчку на иконку
    searchTopInput.slideToggle();
  });


  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
  searchTopInput.keyup(function(){
    searchTopAutocomplete.html('');
    var searchField = searchTopInput.val();
    var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
    $.getJSON('../data/search-autocomplete.json', function(data) {
     $.each(data, function(key, value){
      if (value.request.search(expression) != -1 && searchField !== "") {
        searchTopAutocomplete.show();
        searchTopAutocomplete.append('<li class="page-header__search-request"> '+value.request+' </li>');
        }
     });

    });
 });

  $(document).on('click', 'li.page-header__search-request', function() {
    var clickTopText = $(this).text();
    searchTopInput.val(clickTopText).focus();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="page-header__search page-header__search--top">
  <label for="search-top" class="visually-hidden">Type in a request</label>
  <div class="page-header__search-box"  aria-label="search">
    <input class="page-header__search-input" type="search" id="search-top" placeholder="search" autocomplete="off">
    <button class="page-header__search-icon" type="button"> </button>
    <ul class="page-header__search-autocomplete"></ul>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) кода. И как вы проверяли, что "не работает"? Быть может, обработчик вызывается, но ничего не пишется в `#search` (потому что его нет или потому что он тоже создаётся динамически)...

Comment: Сам input.#search-top есть, скрыт через display none в СSS, появляется по щелчку на иконку, до момента вызова события

Comment: я тут ошибок не вижу, должно работать.

Answer (score 0):

> я тут ошибок не вижу, должно работать

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var searchTopIcon = $('.page-header__search--top .page-header__search-icon ');
  var searchTopInput = $('#search-top');
  var searchTopAutocomplete = $('.page-header__search--top .page-header__search-autocomplete');

  searchTopIcon.click(function(){  // input  скрыт через display none в СSS, появляется по щелчку на иконку
    searchTopInput.slideToggle();
  });

  //$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
  
  searchTopInput.keyup(function(){
    searchTopAutocomplete.html('');
    var searchField = searchTopInput.val();
    var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
    setTimeout(function() { // imitate asynchronicity
      searchTopAutocomplete.show();
      searchTopAutocomplete.append('<li class="page-header__search-request"> '+searchField+' 111 </li>');
      searchTopAutocomplete.append('<li class="page-header__search-request"> '+searchField+' 222 </li>');
      searchTopAutocomplete.append('<li class="page-header__search-request"> '+searchField+' 333 </li>');
    }, 500);
    
 });

  $(document).on('click', 'li.page-header__search-request', function() {
    var clickTopText = $(this).text();
    searchTopInput.val(clickTopText).focus();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="page-header__search page-header__search--top">
  <label for="search-top" class="visually-hidden">Type in a request</label>
  <div class="page-header__search-box"  aria-label="search">
    <input class="page-header__search-input" type="search" id="search-top" placeholder="search" autocomplete="off">
    <button class="page-header__search-icon" type="button">Toggle</button>
    <ul class="page-header__search-autocomplete"></ul>
  </div>
</form>
```